# ENTRYPOINT with environment variables is not acepting new params

Tags: docker, dockerfile

We are creating a simple `Dockerfile`, the last line of that file is

```
 ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "spark-submit --master $SPARK_MASTER script.py"]
```

The `script.py` is a simple pyspark app (is not important for this discussion), this pyspark app receives some parameters that we are trying to pass using the `docker` command as follows

```
 docker run --rm my_spark_app_image --param1 something --param2 something_else
```

But `script.py` is not getting any parameter, i.e. the container executed:

```
 spark-submit --master $SPARK_MASTER script.py
```

The expected behaviour is that the container executes:

```
 spark-submit --master $SPARK_MASTER script.py --param1 something --param2 something_else
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/bin/sh -c` only takes one argument, the script to run. Everything after that argument is a a shell variable `$0`, `$1`, etc, that can be parsed by the script. While you could do this with the `/bin/sh -c` syntax, it's awkward and won't grow with you in the future.

Rather than trying to parse the variables there, I'd move this into an entrypoint.sh that you include in your image:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec spark-submit --master $SPARK_MASTER script.py "$@"
```

And then change the Dockerfile to define:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The `exec` syntax replaces the shell script in PID 1 with the spark-submit process, which allows signals to be passed through. The `"$@"` will pass through any arguments from `docker run`, with each arg quoted in case you have spaces in the parameters. And since it's run by a shell script, the `$SPARK_MASTER` will be expanded.